# Transfer maildir from one server to another

Tags: centos, email

I am transfer a website from one server to another and therefore also need to transfer the old mail (client uses imap on server). I can ssh into the old server and download the Maildir (which is quite big) but I need some instructions on where to go from here?

Maildir folder contents contains (this is from ls -a):

```
.        .Sent   courier.lock           courierimapuiddb      new
..       .Spam   courierimapkeywords    courierpop3dsizelist  tmp
.Drafts  .Trash  courierimapsubscribed  cur
```

Where do I find received/sent messages and where do I put them on the new server (CentOS 5).

Thanks

Comment: Are you running Courier on the new server?

Comment: Can't check right now but I am running Plesk Parallels (mediatemple dv)

Comment: Well, let me rephrase. Do you want to access this folder via IMAP in a similar way on the new server, or do you just want to look at what's in there?

Comment: Yes swap the folder over, so the new server has all the old emails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have both servers reachable via IMAP, I would suggest using [IMAPsync](http://www.linux-france.org/prj/imapsync/), which is written for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Ashley,

Are you moving from one server to another with the same email server, you can simply copy the files across. That said, it is fairly error prone.

Instead, I'd recommend using IMAPsync (as SvenW suggest) or [YippieMove](http://www.yippiemove.com). IMAPsync is free, but a bit tricky to use. YippieMove isn't free, but you'll be up and running in no time, as it is a web service.